# Is Reshiram Shiny locked?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

Can I get a Shiny Reshiram in Omega Ruby? I'm Soft resetting right now. Am I wasting my time?

Answer (score -1):

It actually isn't, but it used to be until recently. Zekrom is also non-shinylocked now.